# Does selenium write and read the webelement values

Tags: python, selenium

I am doing automation using Python2.7 and selenium first time. Now can I write and read as well the below HTML contents?

***Radio Buttons***

```
<form name="myWebForm" action="mailto:youremail@email.com" method="post">
<h4>Please select your favorite food category.</h4>
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : Italian<br />
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : Greek<br />
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : Chinese<br />
<h4>Please select your gender.</h4>
<input type="radio" name="gender" /> : Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" /> : Female<br />
</form>
```

***Single Select List***

```
  <select size="3" name="selectionField" multiple="yes" > 
      <option value="CA" >California -- CA </option>
      <option value="CO" >Colorado -- CO</option>
      <option value="CN" >Connecticut -- CN</option>
    </select>
```

***Defination List***

```
<dl>
<dt>Coffee</dt>
<dd>- black hot drink</dd>
<dt>Milk</dt>
<dd>- white cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

***CheckBoxes***

```
<form name="myWebForm" action="mailto:youremail@email.com" method="post">
<p>Please select every sport that you play.</p>

Soccer: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="soccer"  /><br />

Football: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="football"  /><br /> 

Baseball: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="baseball"  /><br /> 

Basketball: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="basketball"  />

</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, check into xpath

```
x = brower.select_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(), "CO"]')
x.text (print the div text) 
x.click() clicks the div
```

or just

```
brower.select_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(), "CO"]').click()
```

to read the list, this should work;

```
for i in browers.select_elements_by_xpath('//select[@name="selectionField"]//option'):
    print i.text
```

you can select list, radio buttons, span's whatever, just learn Xpath it's worth the effort.

Comment: `click` event will work on select? how the value will be selected by `
click`

Comment: yes click should select the drop down option I edited my answer to include how you could click the Colorado select.

Comment: Then how about the `Read`?

Comment: not sure what you mean when url is called in selenium it is read then.    as soon as the page is pulled up the page contents are read.  so to interact with the read page, you call selectors (xpath, id, class etc...)

Comment: see i am telling the way we are setting the values of each web element,similarly how can I get the values in that web elements previously set?

Comment: I edited once again, to read the items, you have to do a for statement as mentioned above, I cannot test the xpath, but I think it's correct, it locates the select field then grabs all option tags and prints their text.